# How to create new tables in Database for each day in Django

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-models, mariadb

I have an understanding question because I'm thinking about how I should manage my data in Django or the database.

It is a table with about 2000 lines per day and 8 columns. I would like to store all daily data of the last 10 years into the database and add new data every day. It is a good idea to create a database table for each day. In Django, a table is created for each model, but it is not intended for the inventor to create 5000 models in Django.

Is it the only way I use raw SQL to create the tables? Or is there a way I have not discovered in the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer to the question you asked is "Yes, the quickest method would be to use raw SQL," or a variant being dynamically create new models and run makemigrations.

That said, in the absence of more specifics about your problem or task, I must immediately question why you want to dynamically create tables.  For starters, that will lose you the nice Django-provided ORM connections to the schema without more trickery (automatically generated models, daily makemigrations, potential misplaced data *during* migration, specialized code on your part, etc.).  Some thoughts:

1. For almost any web-based project with even minimal capacity, 2000 rows is almost nothing.  Even per day.  After a full year, that's only 730k rows.  Assuming proper schema indexes and [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for your access pattern, that is still considered negligible to an RDBMS.
2. If you truly need to plan for sharding, consider *maybe* doing it at the annual or decadal level.  730K * 10 years is *only* 7.3M rows, which is generally *still* considered in the realm of negligible (given proper normalization and indexes).

If the antecedent to this question is that you are encountering speed issues, then I suggest you need to think hard about your data model's [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and think about where you need to add indexes.  For example, if your default data model does not afford the proper indexes, then use @lodb's (quick fingers!) suggestion and manually tell Django's ORM to create indexes:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['day',]),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Although the daily datasets were sometimes larger than originally thought, so now I have about 13 million records in one table, but that's ok. The table is queried only 1-2 times a day to make a calculation and create a graphic. It also requires only a small part of the data sets. The speed is not that important, so in this case it's the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, a table per day is not the best way to go in Django as it would make the whole framework a lot harder to use:

- you would need to create a new model every day
- you would need to makemigrations and migrate every day
- or you would skip using the ORM altogether

If speed is the reason why you would keep a table per day, I would just use one table, with a database index on the day-field. It might be a little bit slower, but it will make your life a lot easier.

You need to add this to your model-definition:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['day',]),
    ]
```

The manual explains it in more detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/indexes/